# Logcat output as a block of text

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I have an issue I've not seen before using Eclipse and Android.  Logcat is displaying the output from my Samsung Galaxy S3 and my S8 as a block of text instead of parsing it for Level, Time, PID, TID, etc.

I've reset ADB, within DDMS and through the cmd.  I've also rebooted both devices, and my computer, but its still not parsing the output correctly.

BTW, it has worked in the past on this build of Eclipse with my now dead Nexus 7 tablet.

I've included a screen shot to show the problem.  Its making debugging pretty much impossible.

Has anyone experienced this before and found an answer?

[image]

Comment: Maybe because Eclipse is a deprecated IDE for Android development?

Comment: That's true, but I'm not using the latest build tools or targeting the latest version of Android.

Comment: So? Android Studio stills can compile code using old build tools

Answer (score 1):

Do not use **Eclipse** for android developing, **Eclipse** support has ended by Google officially. Use **Android Studio**, it is way much better in many ways.

You will not face such debugging problems in **Android Studio**.

> With the release of Android Studio 2.2, the time has now come to say goodbye to the Eclipse Android Developer Tools. We have formally ended their support and development. There's never been a better time to switch to Android Studio and experience the improvements we've made to the Android development workflow.

[Source](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.tr/2016/11/support-ended-for-eclipse-android.html)

Comment: You're right that Google ended support for Eclipse and eventually I'll have to make the painful move to AS, but ending support doesn't automatically make your development software stop working.

Comment: Google has developing Android Studio since 2012. It was obvious to Eclipse support will end soon. They even waited for ending support to Eclipse since AS version 2.2 released. Almost all developers moved to Android studio, and it is not painful as you think. I moved more than 10 projects into AS. Moving an average project into AS takes 30 mins most. And Bigger projects takes 1-2 hours most. You can even import your old Eclipse shortcuts. If I compare current AS vs Eclipse as an Android IDE, Eclipse is just garbage to me. Emulators even more faster than GenyMotion.

Comment: Thanks Oğuzhan for the advice.  I'm trying to migrate my libgdx projects over to AS.  As bad as you think eclipse is, at lease it only takes a right click to exclude a class from the build path.  I can't find anything like that in AS so far.  :(